# Heltec WiFi LoRa 32 (V3) - Encode/decode packets to binary (make message shorter)

Tags: esp32, lora, esp32-s3

I'm using Heltec WiFi LoRa32 boards (ESP32-S3 + SX1262).

Could you please help me how to encode data e.g. from temperature and humidity sensor into binary or hexadecimal form - to make the LoRa packet length shorter? Similar to what LoRaWAN does.

For example I have two values:

```
float temperature = 21.56;
float humidity = 76.21;
```

I use the official Heltec library for LoRa radio (https://github.com/HelTecAutomation/Heltec_ESP32/blob/master/src/radio/radio.c), I only transfer data via LoRa (not LoRaWAN), so it is necessary to make it work with the library function Radio.Send().

```
Radio.Send( (uint8_t *)txpacket, strlen(txpacket) ); //send the package out
```

I found this example: https://create.arduino.cc/editor/LogMaker360/770f60c9-52c5-4d29-b417-4804b278db20/preview
and this tutorial: https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/docs/devices/bytes/

I'm confused in this, so I would appreciate a parto of code example compatible with Heltec library for encoding and decoding compatible with Heltec library functions.

Thank you

Comment: `21.56` can be represented by two bytes as `2156`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send both temperature and humidity in a single packet,
the easiest way is to define the packet as a `struct` with two fields:

```cpp
struct LoraData {
    float temperature;
    float humidity;
};
```

You can then send the raw bytes by typecasting the address of such a
`struct` to `uint8_t*`. This, however, is generally not recommended,
because it violates C++ type aliasing rules. You can circumvent this
issue by defining a `union`:

```cpp
union LoraPacket {
    LoraData data;
    uint8_t bytes[sizeof(LoraData)];
};
```

This represents an area of memory that can be interpreted as containing
either the numeric data `data`, or an array of bytes. Then you can fill
the `data` field and send the raw bytes:

```cpp
void send_dummy_data()
{
    LoraPacket packet = {
        .data = {
            .temperature = 12.56,
            .humidity = 76.21
        }
    };
    Radio.Send(packet.bytes, sizeof packet);
}
```

At the other end, you do the same thing backwards: you fill in the bytes
and read back the numeric data:

```cpp
void rx_done(uint8_t *payload, uint16_t size, int16_t, int8_t)
{
    if (size != sizeof(LoraPacket)) {  // sanity check
        Serial.println("Bad packet size");
        return;
    }
    LoraPacket packet;
    memcpy(&packet.bytes, payload, size);
    Serial.print("temperature: ");
    Serial.println(packet.data.temperature);
    Serial.print("humidity: ");
    Serial.println(packet.data.humidity);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Radio.Send( (uint8_t *)txpacket, strlen(txpacket) );

Noted that `strlen(txpacket)` is only applicable if the `txpacket` is a string. Since temperature is a floating point value, it should be `sizeof(temperature)`(see further explanation below).

I think there is a misunderstanding that this send a "shorter" data because you saw the `uint8_t`, but it is not the case. A single-precision floating point data is stored as a 4-byte data in according to [IEEE754 format](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ieee-standard-754-floating-point-numbers/). What the `RadioSend((uint8_t *) temperature, sizeof(temperature))` does is it simply cast the floating point value to a pointer of byte (i.e. uint8_t) that is point to the beginning of the `temperature` in memory so that it can send the data byte-by-byte, the `sizeof(temperature)` is equivalent to `sizeof(float)` so it is equal to 4. The data that going through the radio transmission is still 4-byte floating point value.

To send the temperature and humidity, you just need to send the temperature and humidity data as:

```c
float temperature = 21.56;
float humidity = 76.21;

RadioSend((uint8_t *) temperature, sizeof(temperature));
RadioSend((uint8_t *) humidity, sizeof(humidity));
```

However, as point out by @jsotola, if you want, there is a way to reduce the data to be sent from 4-byte floating point to 2-byte `int16_t` by converting the `float` to `int16_t` by multiply the floating point value with 100. The converted data is only 2-byte long as an `int16_t` without losing the precision of the floating point (which has precision of 2 decimal points).

```cpp
float temperature = 21.56;
float humidity = 76.21;

int16_t temperature_in_integer = (int16_t) temperature * 100; // integer 2156
int16_t humidity_in_integer = (int16_t) humidity * 100;  // integer 7621

// send 2-byte each
RadioSend((uint8_t *) temperature_in_integer, sizeof(temperature_in_integer));
RadioSend((uint8_t *) humidity_in_integer, sizeof(humidity_in_integer));
```

On the receiving end, the received data need to be divided by 100 to get back the actual temperature and humidity value.

If this is a little confuse to you, I would suggest you pick up a [book of C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) or [C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/) and learn the foundation of  data types, data casting and pointer.

Comment: Glad to hear that, if this helps, consider to accept it as answer by clicking the "tick" sign.

Comment: But what about if I want to send the values in one packet - how to pack it? Especially when on some nodes I measure different kind of values?

And how to deal with the received data on the receiver's side?

Thanks

Comment: You don't need to purposely pack it, it send 4+4 bytes. Personally I don't know how internally the RadioSend and Lora handle the data, so I can' really answer that. For receiving, the int16_t data is quite straightforward. For float, you can read my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78169013/how-to-receive-a-float-array-using-esp8266-via-i2c/78170406#78170406) on how to read back the `float` from the received buffer.

Comment: I need to send all values in one packet and then on the receiver's side decode it and seperate the palyoad to individual values. Is this possible?

Comment: Come to think about it, You can create an array of float (or a struct of float) and send in 8-byte all together. array[0] be the temperature value and array[2] be the humidity value.

Comment: I also has an example on my [blog](https://www.e-tinkers.com/2020/05/esp-01-range-test-with-esp-now-protocol/) which show pack temperature and humidity in a struct and send over transmission. You can take a look at that. If you have further question, you should raise in a separate question, the StackOverflow/StackExchange is better for one question at a time. Not keep adding questions when one has been answered.

Comment: Ok, and is it possible to somehow ensure that when measuring different variables to determine which variable is in the packet at a given position or do I just need to know?

For example, if I send temperature and humidity from one device and pressure, voltage and current from another?

Or just have a position for each variable in the packet, and in case it will not be measured leave for example zero?

Thanks