# Heltec WiFi LoRa 32 (V3) - Difference of various datatype packets length

Tags: lora, esp32-s3

I'm using Heltec WiFi LoRa32 boards (ESP32-S3 + SX1262).

For example I have two measured values:

```
float temperature = 21.56;
float humidity = 76.21;
```

I use the official Heltec library for LoRa radio (https://github.com/HelTecAutomation/Heltec_ESP32/blob/master/src/radio/radio.c), I only transfer data via LoRa (not LoRaWAN), so it is necessary to make it work with the library function Radio.Send().

```
Radio.Send( (uint8_t *)txpacket, strlen(txpacket) ); //send the package out
```

I would like to know if I spare the data length amount when I'll send values via LoRa in floats like:

```
void loop() {
  if (lora_idle)  {
    delay(1000);
    Paylaod payload;
    payload.temperature = random(-1000, 1000) / 10.0;
    payload.humidity = random(0, 101) / 100.0;
    
    Radio.Send( (uint8_t *)&payload, sizeof payload);
    Serial.print("sending packet: temperature = ");
    Serial.print(payload.temperature, 2);
    Serial.print(" and humidity = ");
    Serial.println(payload.humidity, 2);
    lora_idle = false;
  }
  Radio.IrqProcess( );
}
```

instead of sending them as chars like:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 30 // Define the payload size here

char txpacket[BUFFER_SIZE];


void loop()
{
    if(lora_idle == true)
    {
    delay(1000);

        sprintf(txpacket,"21.5676.24");  //start a package
   
        Serial.printf("\r\nsending packet \"%s\" , length %d\r\n",txpacket, strlen(txpacket));

        Radio.Send( (uint8_t *)txpacket, strlen(txpacket) ); //send the package out 
    lora_idle = false;
    }
  Radio.IrqProcess( );
}
```

If I spare the number of transmitted bytes, how many bytes occupy one character in `char txpacket[BUFFER_SIZE]`?

Thanks

Comment: what are you using to measure temperature and humidity?

Comment: I'm using SHT31 sensor

Comment: the sensor is not accurate to two decimal places... it makes no sense to transmit floating point values

Comment: It basically doesn't matter which values are transmitted, but my question is how to effectively send  multiple values by LoRa.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Heltec WiFi LoRa 32 (V3) - Encode/decode packets to binary (make message shorter)](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/95833/heltec-wifi-lora-32-v3-encode-decode-packets-to-binary-make-message-shorter)